# Model Popup state

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, umbraco7

I am displaying a form in Jquery model popup using MVC Partial View. On submit I call my action method to validate user input and if validation fails I need to populate the modal popup again. The problem I face is,on submit it calls the child action method, I'm able to get the ViewData.ModelState.IsValid in my partial view however not been able to auto display the modal popup depends on ModelState value. I tries below jquery code but no luck.

**Partial View**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<WebApplicationDemo1.Models.JobAlertModel>

<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 550,
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "dissolve",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
            });
        });
</script>



<button id="modal-opener">Job Alerts</button>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Product</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.email )
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.location)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.location)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.location)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.search)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.search)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.search)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create new job alert" />

        </fieldset>
    }



</div>

@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div>There are some errors</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#modal-opener").click();
    </script>
}
```

**Child Action**

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult JobAlert(JobAlertModel JobAlert)
    {
        JobAlertModel ja = new JobAlertModel();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ja.email = JobAlert.email;

            return Redirect("/");
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("popup", ja);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out myself. In case somebody want to know.

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#modal-opener").click();
        });

    </script>
}
```